# start date is less than end date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following code is working fine with any start time and end time but when i give the end time 12 am or 12 pm the following code not giving the correct output.

```
var startTime = $("#txtStartTime").val();                 eg. 7:00 PM
var from = new Date("November 13, 2013 " + startTime);
from = from.getTime();                                    eg. 1384349400000
var endTime = $("#txtEndTime").val();                     eg. 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM
var to = new Date("November 13, 2013 " + endTime);
to = to.getTime();                                        eg. 1384281000000
if (from > to || from == to) 
{
     html += "<li>Start-time must be smaller than End-time</li>";

}
```

for example :
when i give start time 7:00 PM and end time 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM it shows me Start-time must be smaller than End-time.
Can you please tell me how can i fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW.. 7:00 PM is greater than 12:00 AM.. Which says correct.

Comment: The time difference is 68400000 milliseconds, which is 9 hours. That would indicate that 10:00 AM was entered as the end time.

Comment: How can i change following date to   2014-07-29 12:00 AM                                                                   Tue Jul 29 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 12:00 AM

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* 12am or 12pm (see [here](http://www.npl.co.uk/science-technology/time-frequency/time/faqs/is-midnight-12-a.m.-or-12-p.m.-(faq-time)) for example), the whole definition of those terms (ante and post meridian) means that it's neither am nor pm on the 12 o'clock time itself.

For the first case, it's indisputably correct. Whether 12am is mid-day on the 13th, or midnight between the 12th and 13th, 7pm *is* greater.

The second case you could argue either that 12pm represents midday on the 13th or midnight between the 13th and 14th. In the former case, it is again correct. The latter case not so much.

Best bet would probably to see what difference there is between 12pm and 12:01pm (either one minute or just shy of twelve hours). That will tell you how it's interpreting 12pm.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out:

```
// This represents: Thu Nov 13 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
var date1 = new Date('November 13, 2013 07:00 PM');

// This represents: Thu Nov 13 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
var date2 = new Date('November 13, 2013 12:00 PM');

// This represents: Thu Nov 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
var date3 = new Date('November 13, 2013 12:00 AM'):
```

Therefore:

```
date1 > date2 > date3;
```

This might make more intuitive sense if you convert the numbers to their 24hour counterparts.

If you did,

> 12:00 AM becomes 00:00.
>   12:00 PM becomes 12:00. 
>   7:00 PM becomes 19:00.

Therefore, 00:00 < 12:00 < 19:00 and 12:00 AM < 12:00 PM < 7:00 PM. So your **from** is always greater than your **to** in this situation.

In other words, it's working as intended :)